# When only network connect, another app execute on Android

Tags: android

I want when I start A app.

This my code:

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

netCheckAutoUpdate();
.
.
.
public void netCheckAutoUpdate() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    int iNetwork = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1: activeNetwork.getType();

    if (iNetwork ==cm.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name");
        startActivity(intent);
    else if (iNetwork == cm.TYPE_WIFI) {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name");
        startActivity(intent);
    else {
    }
}
```

But now, when connect WIFI, ETHERNET, unable network always start another package app.

I want when unable network, not execute another app.

How can I do it programmatically?

**Update:**

`netCheckAutoUpdate` is check my device network state. If current network state connect Ethernet, that start another app and current network state connect WI-FI, that start another app.

Finally current network state connect nothing , that not start another app.

But if not connect network, start another app.

Comment: Your Question is not clear, please explain more.

Comment: Sorry. I add questionm